# If my new faucet hoses don't fit on the shutoff valve should I replace the valve or use an adapter?

Tags: plumbing

I'm replacing my kitchen faucet and the new faucet has 3/8" fittings on the hot/cold hoses, but the shutoff valves have 1/2" openings. Would it be better to replace the shutoff valves, or find an adapter [like this?](http://www.lowes.com/pd_645784-72906-66CA-6-8XY+P_0__?productId=50380894&Ntt=compression%20adapter&pl=1&currentURL=%3FNtt%3Dcompression%2Badapter%26page%3D1&facetInfo=)

Answer (score 1):

In this case it would be a lot better to just replace the shut off valves, by adding an adapter you are just adding one more thing to break or go wrong and cause leaks!   -7 years plumbing experience and red seal certified (Canada)

Comment: One problem I foresee, and I need to confirm, is that the dishwasher might also have a 1/2" opening. So even if I were to replace the shutoff valves, I'd have to put an adapter on the new one for the dishwasher -- unless there's such a thing as a 3-way shutoff valve with a 3/8" and 1/2"?

Comment: Do you have a picture of thee current set up? I would recommend having your cold go directly to the tap with the new valve on it and then have your hot come up, have a tee with the valve on top to go to your sink and then a short piece of pipe coming out of the side of that tee to go to your dishwasher valve and this to your dishwasher, this could easily be done with copper and/or plastic depending on yor current set up

Comment: Would you recommend replacing the compression ring and nut, or use the same one if I can?

Comment: I would recommend replacing it, they usually stretch over time and this could lead to leaks

Comment: I replaced the valves entirely but wound up with a small leak behind each new nut (pics: http://imgur.com/a/xPou8 ). The drip shown is after leaving the water running on high for a few minutes to test. I've tightened each nut as much as I can manage -- is there any way to correct it other than pulling off the valves again?

Comment: These are compression fittings, I would recommend taking then back apart, then sliding both the but and the compression ring onto the pipe, then place your valve on top and slide up the nut and compression ring, you may also need to put a wrench on the valve body and a wrench on the nut to get it as right as needed

Comment: Do you think the ferrule will come off again after I've already tightened it?

Comment: Look at you using the fancy names! Yes it will though, if it is leaking then it hasn't sealed properly and will still come off, I would also suggest tightening the packing just to ensure that this is not the issue as well

Answer (score 0):

Use the adapter. Why go through all the trouble of installing a new shutoff, if you don't have to.

If you're using any fittings that have rubber washers, don't over tighten them. The washer could be crushed, deformed, or pushed out of the way.

Comment: FIP to compression fittings are in no way wrong. You have to make the reduction somewhere. There are not any rubber parts on the fitting from the link. I would not use rubber washer fittings, they are temporary. You want compression fittings to deform a bit. So if there are rubber parts, that I do not see, go with tester101's answer